# Webpack fails to find scss in node_modules

Tags: css, node.js, webpack, sass, sass-loader

Webpack isn't able to find scss in node_modules

```
  {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          { loader: 'css-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              includePaths: ['./node_modules'],
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

and in a SCSS file..
`@import '~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';`

```
@import '~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: ~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.
```

Comment: Did you try to remove `~`?

Comment: Yes same issue.

Comment: The ~ is fine you can leave it there. Try with my answer to see if it work

Comment: Same problem here, any solution?